# Recovering data after process restart

Tags: linux, transactions, persistence

I have this requirement in a x86 based Linux system running 2.6.3x kernel..

My process has some dynamic data (not much, in few Mega Bytes range) that has to be recovered if the process crashes. obvious solution is to store the data in shared memory and read it again if the process re-starts. Write to shared memory has to be done carefully so that a process crash in the middle of update won't leave the data corrupted in the shared memory.

Before coding this myself just wanted to check if there is any open source program/library that provides this functionality.. Thanks.

-Santhosh.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think your proposed design is sound. An OS crash (e.g. power failure etc), may cause a mmap'd area to be partially sync'd to disc (maybe the pages are written out in a different order than you wrote them etc), which means your data structures will get corrupted in arbitrary ways.

If you need your database changes to be durable and atomic (maybe consistency and integrity wouldn't hurt either, right?) then I'd strongly recommend using an existing database system which supports ACID, or the appropriate subset. Maybe sqlite or Berkeley DB would do the trick.

You could do it yourself, in principle, but not in the way that you've described - you'd need to create some kind of log file which was updated in a way which could be read back atomically, and be able to "replay" events from some known snapshot etc, which is technically challenging.

Remember that:

- An OS failure might cause a write initiated by msync() or similar, to be partially completed to durable disc
- mmap does not guarantee to never write back data at other times, i.e. when you haven't called msync() for a while
- Pages aren't necessarily written back in the same order that you modified the pages in memory - e.g. you can write to a[0] and then a[4096], and have a[4096] durable but a[0] not after a crash.
- Even flushing an individual page is not absolutely guaranteed to be atomic.

I realise that using a library (e.g. bdb or sqlite) for every read or write operation to your data structure is an intrusive change, but if you want this kind of robustness, I think it's necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. One clarification though.. I need the data to be restored only when my process restarts. If the OS crashes then I don't have to. For writing to shared memory I was thinking of just creating a file in /dev/shm. Anything written to /dev/shm (ie: tempfs) never gets written to the disk, isn't it ?

Comment: I had assumed that your data had to survive not just an app crash, but also an OS crash, power failure or other hardware failure. Making a database which cannot do so, is generally pointless, as "real systems" have to survive such failures all the time.